# Retrieve the selected ListBoxItem Tag

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I retrieve the Tag from a listbox item?   I have built a list by pulling values from a file and generated textboxes with the parsed data then I made the textboxes a chile of the border.  Then I add the border to the listboxitem.   So I want to add a tag with a string value and then retrieve that invisible value using the selected item.

So I set the tag...

```
//created a border above
ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
item.Tag = path;
item.Content = myBorder;
listBox.Items.Add(item);
```

Now when that item is selected and I want to read that tag how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you are using the text-box you could try something like this

```
if(lb.SelectedItem != -1)

    {
        string selectedTagx = ((TextBox)lb.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
        //if just a listbox item
         string selectedTagx = ((ListBoxItem)lb.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: This was perfect!  The TextBox will work too but the ListBoxItem part was exactly what I needed.   Right on!

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following to your window or usercontrol that holds the listbox

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //created a border above
        ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
        item.Tag = path;
        item.Content = myBorder;
        listBox.Items.Add(item);

        listBox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(listBox_SelectionChanged);
    }

    void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = (listBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem).Tag as string;
    }
```

Where "MainWindow()" is the constructor of your window or usercontrol

You can also add the event handler in xaml instead of in the constructor

```
<ListBox Height="100" Name="listBox" Width="120"
                 SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```